# React - external links not working after deployment

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-bootstrap

I have an issue where in the development build the link for my [blog](https://juniorlearnstocode.blogspot.ba/), in the main menu works just as it is supposed to, but after I bundled it up and [deployed everything to Firebase](https://mirza-sisic.firebaseapp.com/) the link does not open, it just reloads the app and this URL shows up: https://mirza-sisic.firebaseapp.com/juniorlearnstocode.blogspot.ba

Here is what my Menu component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from '../../../src/Images/MirzaLogo.png';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';


const Menu = () => (
<Navbar inverse fixedTop collapseOnSelect>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
    <a href="#headerwrap"><img alt="MS logo" src={Logo}/></a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#aboutwrap">
          About
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#Resume">
          Resume
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#workwrap">
         Projects
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#Clients">
        Clients
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#Contact">
           Contact
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" eventKey={2} href="https:juniorlearnstocode.blogspot.ba">
           Blog
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
);

export default Menu;
```

[image: External link issue]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be http://yourblog

Comment: Also the URL is missing // after https:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the URL(https://juniorlearnstocode.blogspot.ba) and it worked.

I uploaded it to my sample working website,

http://johnwebsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Clicking on the blog opens in new tab and not same tab.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a click handler on your nav item and use this code to open a new window:

```
let clickHandler=()={
    window.open(blogURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out! I just replaced the NavItem component with MenuItem component and now  **target="_blank"** behaves as it should by opening the link in a new browser tab:

```
   <MenuItem href={externalLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" eventKey={2}>
       Blog
   </MenuItem>
```

Thanks for the helpful insight everyone!